# Is 'What I prefer is to spending time with you' correct grammatically?

Tags: present-continuous, infinitive-vs-gerund, to-infinitive

I have seen a promotional video for [Beyond the Future in Mr Love: Queen's Choice](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IEOXHLSSYoQ), I copied its lines and want to rewrite them to practice my expression and grammar.

Here is the one confused me of the lines:

> Whether it's a play or a game, **what I want is to spend time** with you.

There is a problem I met, I want to use *prefer doing* to replace the original *want to do* as follow:

> Whether it's a play or a game, **what I prefer is to spending time** with you.

But then I hesitated, I am not very sure this is correct grammatically, maybe it only ought to be rewritten as this, I know which is correct:

> Whether it's a play or a game, **what I prefer is spending time** with you.

So are they both correct? May you tell me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is \`enjoy to \[verb\]\` incorrect?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17259/why-is-enjoy-to-verb-incorrect) Also [passive Gerunds to express likes or dislikes](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/105414/) and ["I like to be loved" vs. "I like being loved"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/67496/) and [passive Gerunds to express likes or dislikes](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/105414/passive-gerunds-to-express-likes-or-dislikes), among others.

Answer (score 1):

First, the expressions are *to spend time* and *spending time* - never *to spending time* (but see the note at the end).

Secondly, some words (verbs, adjectives) require one or other of these constructions, some allow either. So

> I like spending time with you *or* I like to spend time with you.

But

> I enjoy spending time with you, *not* *I enjoy to spend time with you.

(The * means "not grammatical).

Conversely

> I hope to spend time with you, *but not* *I hope spending time with you.

You cannot predict from the meaning that *like* will take either construction, that *enjoy* takes only an *-ing* clause and that *hope* takes only a *to*-infinitive clause: these are details that just have to be learnt.

**Note** *prefer* takes a *to* phrase as its standard of comparison:

> I prefer apples **to** oranges.

This is quite separate from the *to* in a *to*-infinitive clause, and can be combined with an *-ing* clause:

> I prefer reading a book to spending time with you.

This is grammatical: it is not the sort of mixed clause I described above as unacceptable: it is the preposition *to* followed by an *-ing* clause.

Comment: I think it's worth explicitly pointing out that we can use infinitives for "X rather than Y" comparisons - in which case the word ***than*** is required, not the preposition ***to***. *I [would] prefer **to** starve [rather] **than** [to] eat that!*. Where both instances of ***to*** are infinitive markers (but the second can be "deleted" as being a predictable repetition of the first one, in a parallel construction).